# Facebook App permission requests get disable by the user using the new authentication

Tags: php, authentication, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm using this code for the app authentication:

```
    //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
if(empty($_REQUEST["code"])){ 
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
    . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
    . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
    .  "&scope=publish_stream,user_birthday";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url 
    . "'</script>");
}
else {
        $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
    . "client_id=" . $app_id
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
    . "&code=" . $code
    . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url);
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];
}
```

In the new facebook authentication, the user have the option to choose one of the permission request and cancel it after he click on "Log in" button. for example, the user can disable the request for publish_stream or user_birthday access and still to log into my app.
I saw that Zynga and many others still using the old authentication request that looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESigT.png (some picture that I've found in the net)

but for some reason in the last 2 weeks my request for permission dialog got changed to the new one:
http://i52.tinypic.com/qstm6g.png (some picture that I've found in the net)

How can I switch it back to the old permission dialog? that is only 1 single dialog box and not 2-3 dialog box till the user get logged into my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm not sure if new apps can switch back, and even if you can...it's not recommended since all apps will migrate to the new one soon.
2. Even with Zynga apps, the user can always revoke these permissions from his/her app privacy settings
3. You need to deal with the case when a permission is revoked. This is explained in this blog [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/576/).

Comment: But I see many people that creating new apps still get the old permission dialog, why is that?

Comment: Maybe they have the *Enhanced Auth Dialog* option disabled. Again, **you** should handle the case when a user revoke a permission **not** trying to hide it! :-)

Comment: What will happen if ill disable the Enhanced Auth Dialog? is it going to be the only option (by default) in the near future by facebook? thanks

Comment: Well, it's placed in the **Migrations** section...so I would assume it'll be the only option, yes.